# Mount TrueCrypt encrypted system drive on other computer?

Tags: mount, operating-system, truecrypt

I have bought a new HDD for installing a new operating system. Can I, in case I'm missing files, attach the old TrueCrypt-encrypted hard disk to USB and mount it in TrueCrypt?

Or doesn't this work for system-encrypted hard disks?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the TrueCrypt GUI, choose the partion of the external drive, then select "Mount without Pre-Boot authentication" from the Tools menu.

This will let you mount the volume as if it were an encrypted device without the boot loader (the difference just being a few offsets as to where TrueCrypt should attempt to decrypt the volume header from)

Comment: I took a copy of an encrypted partition onto a USB drive using Knoppix and using the `dd` tool to byte-copy the partition. Later, back in Windows, the TrueCrypt GUI + Mount without pre-boot authentication option doesn't successfully mount the USB partition..

Comment: In the 'Mount without pre-boot authentication option'-window the keyboard is changed to default/native (?), so if you use dvorak you might find yourself with a qwerty layout. I belief Truecrypt switches to the bios-level keyboard layout.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the [system encryption feature](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=system-encryption) of **TrueCrypt** binds to the other hardware.
You should be able to use the encrypted disk on other systems.

You will need the **TrueCrypt boot loader engaged in the boot process** to unlock the system encryption on that drive. The [TrueCrypt Rescue Disk](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/rescue-disk) might be useful for this.

However, there is always the **option of booting from that drive and removing encryption** (which works in place) before using it this way -- could take some time depending on the drive size.